# What is the best practice to navigate instead of Using A Tag In AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my Profile Block Code:

```
<div class="avatars-list">
  <a href="#" class="avatar-item">
    <img src="img/users/user-1.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="img-fluid">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="avatar-item">
    <img src="img/users/user-5.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="img-fluid">
  </a>
</div>
```

Shall i replace `<a>` tag with some `<div>, <span>`

Actually, we can write a function for each item to navigate to a particalar page right!!

Comment: Best practise is to use an `<a>`. It comes with built-in features essential for accessibility (such as being in the focus order and allowing screen readers to announce it as a link).

Comment: Why would you **not** use an `<a>`?  Why do you think you shouldn't?

Comment: It is best to always use the `<a>` tag for navigation. You can always add an `ng-click` into the tag: `<a ng-click="doSomething()"><img...></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this 
on html

```
<div ng-click="navigate()"></div>
```

on js

```
$scope.navigate = function () {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}
```

Comment: But, how do we give different Links for each <element>